# How do I refresh my list view adapter?

Tags: android

I am having problem with this, it is OK if I switch between fragment. But when I exit from another activity, it does not refresh.

I am a bit weak on this, if possible, please indicate where to add codes, thank y'll

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorite_page, null);

    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_favorite);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new BaseAdapter() {
        ...
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
            ...
            convertView = tv;
            return convertView;
        }
    };
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    List<FavoriteBean> favData = DataSupport.findAll(FavoriteBean.class);
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.a);
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(LoadFiles.getString(inputStream));
        JSONArray jarry = obj.getJSONArray("items");
       ...
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
((BaseAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Comment: I tried but did not work, can u kindly show tell me which exact line I shall add this code or which code shall be replaced?

Answer (score 0):

use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();